# iText7 PDF renders correctly but prints incorrect in Adobe Reader

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7, watermark

I have a task of adding watermarks to a lot of existing PDFs and I use iText7 for this in C#. The result can be seen in this picture (Blank pdf used)

[image: PDF on screen]

It renders fine everywhere and prints perfectly from both Chrome and Edge. However, when printed from Adobe Acrobat Reader, this is what happens:

[image: Print preview in Adobe reader]

Anyone knowing more about PDF than I, who can help with this issue? I am using version 7.1.13 of iText.

The test pdf is available here:

https://potanteststorage.blob.core.windows.net/pdf/Test.pdf

C# Code:

```cs
public static void AddProductionWatermarks(string sourceFile, string destinationPath)
{
    float watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth = 75;
    float watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight = 250;

    //Custom text
    float formWidth = 75;
    float formHeight = 250;
    float formXOffset = 0;
    float formYOffset = 0;

    float xTranslation = 50;
    float yTranslation = 0;

    double rotationInRads = Math.PI / 2;

    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN);
    float fontSize = 12;

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFile), new PdfWriter(destinationPath));
    var numberOfPages = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();
    PdfPage page = null;

    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
        Rectangle ps = page.GetPageSize();

        //PRODUCTION watermark -------------------------------------------------------
        float prodBottomLeftX = -20;
        float prodBottomLeftY = ps.GetHeight() / 2;

        Rectangle prodWatermarkTrimmingRectangle = new Rectangle(prodBottomLeftX, prodBottomLeftY, watermarkTrimmingRectangleWidth, watermarkTrimmingRectangleHeight);
        PdfWatermarkAnnotation prodWatermark = new PdfWatermarkAnnotation(prodWatermarkTrimmingRectangle);

        AffineTransform transform2 = new AffineTransform();
        transform2.Translate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
        transform2.Rotate(rotationInRads);

        PdfFixedPrint fixedPrint2 = new PdfFixedPrint();
        prodWatermark.SetFixedPrint(fixedPrint2);

        PdfFormXObject form2 = new PdfFormXObject(formRectangle);
        PdfCanvas canvas2 = new PdfCanvas(form2, pdfDoc);

        transform2.GetMatrix(transformValues);
        canvas2.SaveState()
            .BeginText().SetColor(new DeviceRgb(255, 36, 0), true)
            .SetTextMatrix(transformValues[0], transformValues[1], transformValues[2], transformValues[3], transformValues[4], transformValues[5])
            .SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize)
            .ShowText("PRODUCTION")
            .EndText()
            .RestoreState();

        canvas2.Release();

        prodWatermark.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, new PdfAnnotationAppearance(form2.GetPdfObject()));
        prodWatermark.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        page.AddAnnotation(prodWatermark);
    }

    page?.Flush();
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're probably going to need to share the actual PDF file rather than pictures (which are very useful for describing the problem). Best bet is probably to put the PDF file on a file sharing service (eg DropBox) and link to it here, you can edit your answer to add the URL.

Comment: Thx KenS, added now.

Comment: You use **FixedPrint** dictionaries in your annotations. Thus, you ask for special treatment of the watermark during printing.

Comment: mkl, you are amazing! I should have read more about the usage of FixedPrint. I thought it was related to how the watermark was printed on the PDF page. Simply removing those two lines fixed it. Thx!

Comment: Great. I'll make that an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use **FixedPrint** dictionaries in your annotations:

```
PdfFixedPrint fixedPrint2 = new PdfFixedPrint();
prodWatermark.SetFixedPrint(fixedPrint2);
```

This additional entry for **Watermark** annotations specifies how this annotation shall be drawn relative to the dimensions of the target media during printing. Thus, *you ask for special treatment of the watermark during printing*.

So if you indeed want special treatment during printing (merely not the current treatment), simply set the `PdfFixedPrint` properties accordingly.

If you don't want any special treatment during printing, don't set a `PdfFixedPrint` object at all.